# Place image on the left of a button, and keep the image fit the button

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I want an image on the left of the text, but I also want the image to fit the button (not bigger than the button or too small). There seems to be two options:`BackgroundImage` and `Image` property.

[image]

If I use `BackgroundImage`, I can make the image fit the button size, but the image always seems to be placed on the centre. If I use `Image`, I can place the image on the left of the text, but then the image does not fit the button.

Is there any way to get both?

---

As requested, I attached the source code. I just used the GUI designer and the code was generated by it, so it contains lots of lines. In short, I made the top two buttons use `Background` and the bottom two buttons use `Image`.

```
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this.button2.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
        this.button2.Image = global::delete_menu.Properties.Resources.folder;
        this.button2.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(63, 158);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(118, 25);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button2.Text = "image";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("button1.BackgroundImage")));
        this.button1.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
        this.button1.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip1;
        this.button1.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(204, 63);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(245, 56);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "background";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // button3
        // 
        this.button3.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
        this.button3.Image = global::delete_menu.Properties.Resources.folder;
        this.button3.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(204, 158);
        this.button3.Name = "button3";
        this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(245, 56);
        this.button3.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button3.Text = "image";
        this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // button4
        // 
        this.button4.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("button4.BackgroundImage")));
        this.button4.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
        this.button4.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        this.button4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(63, 63);
        this.button4.Name = "button4";
        this.button4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(118, 25);
        this.button4.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button4.Text = "background";
        this.button4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(505, 278);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button4);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.contextMenuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

Comment: Check the BackgroundImageLayout https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagelayout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you post the code that you used to get these four buttons?

Comment: In the screen capture above, the top two buttons have it set to `Zoom`. That is why the icon fits the button. As for the bottom two buttons, the `Image` property does not seem to be affected by `BackgroundImageLayout`